# Is it possible to hide a .glade file from user in GTK?

Tags: c, gtk, glade

I am new at GTK and started out using Glade to design a UI. But whenever I run my app, I must keep the Glade file in the same directory as the executable. I would like to distribute the Glade file in a compiled form, same as the source code. Is this possible?

Comment: Why down-voted ?

Comment: nowadays, ui/glade files are mostly bundled as resources inside the executable binary but you can choose a different path from the one you are using. There's some degree of flexibility.  Check [meson build system](http://mesonbuild.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's possible. Give a look to the [GResource](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GResource.html) documentation. Its main use is to embed resources like ui files, icons, etc. in the main binary.

Answer (score 0):

I realise that this post is almost 5 years old but, for the benefit of others who stumble across this issue (IE, like me), here is my work-around.
In Gtk+-3.0, you can import your glade xml via either a local file or from a string. IE:

```
builder = gtk_builder_new_from_string(myGladeStr,strlen(myGladeStr));
```

Write a little app to convert the glade xml file to a 'C' compatible 'string' format. IE, replace ' " ' with ' \" ' and add a '\' to the end of each line. I also include the declaration and return functions meaning, any adjustments to a glade file is a simple as running this app >> gladeFileString1.c etc.

This way, you can store your glade xml's in a 'C' file, as a string, an not externally to your app.

Comment: The "little app" to which you refer already exists, see `glib-compile-resources`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how xnec2c does it:

**=== src/Makefile.am ===**

```
PKGCONFIG = $(shell which pkg-config)
GLIB_COMPILE_RESOURCES = $(shell $(PKGCONFIG) --variable=glib_compile_resources gio-2.0)

xnec2c-resources.c: ../resources/xnec2c.gresource.xml $(shell $(GLIB_COMPILE_RESOURCES) --sourcedir=../resources --generate-dependencies ../resources/xnec2c.gresource.xml)
    $(GLIB_COMPILE_RESOURCES) --sourcedir=../resources --target=xnec2c-resources.c --generate-source ../resources/xnec2c.gresource.xml
```

**=== resources/xnec2c.gresource.xml ===**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gresources>
  <gresource prefix="/">
    <file>xnec2c.glade</file>
    <file>xnec2c.svg</file>
    <file>link.svg</file>
    <file>unlink.svg</file>
  </gresource>
</gresources>
```

Then be sure to compile and link the resulting .c file into your project. In this case it is `xnec2c-resources.c`

Here is the commit that implemented exactly what you're asking for:

- https://github.com/KJ7LNW/xnec2c/commit/e57c92f9d75ef50167bffe1da444fe3d2f2401cd

And here are some other relevant references:

- https://github.com/KJ7LNW/xnec2c/blob/master/src/Makefile.am#L58
- https://github.com/KJ7LNW/xnec2c/blob/master/resources/xnec2c.gresource.xml
- https://github.com/KJ7LNW/xnec2c/tree/master/resources